# Error: "Generator NMake Makefiles does not support platform specification, but platform x64 was specified."

Tags: python, cmake, gnu-make, h.265, gnuwin32

I am trying to install Fraunhofer Versatile Video Encoder (VVenC) through CMake. It show the error below.

```
cmake --build build/static --config Release  -- /maxcpucount:8 /verbosity:minimal /nr:false
CMake Error:
  Generator

    NMake Makefiles

  does not support platform specification, but platform

    x64

  was specified.


make: *** [release] Error 1
```

Why is it happening and how to fix it?